# 現行のxcodeで古いVerのiOSをデバッグする方法について

Tags: swift, xcode

iPhoneアプリ開発初心です。

Xcode10.3を使用しております。

iOS9.0のシミュレータでデバッグ作業を行いたいのですが、
simulator一覧を見てもiOS 10.3.1以降のものしか存在しません。

一定以上の古いVerはテストできない仕様なのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

少なくともシミュレータが入っていなければ、まず古いXcodeをダウンロードして古いシミュレータをインストールする必要があります。過去のXcodeのバージョンは https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ からすべてダウンロードできるので必要なバージョンをダウンロードしてください。

古いXcodeをインストールしたなら、そのXcodeを使ってテストするのが一番簡単です。

ただし、macOSのバージョンによって動作するXcodeのバージョンに限界があるので（例えばCatalinaはXcode 9.xは動作しない）、そのような場合は古いOSが動いているMacを準備する必要があります。

そうなると、古いMacを手に入れるより中古のiPhoneを探す方が簡単かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。xcodeの仕様なのですね。

Comment: 度々質問、失礼します。古いxcodeをインストールした際に、最低限保証されるシミュレータのバージョンが一目で分かるような一覧表はございますでしょうか。１つ１つxcodeを入れてシミュレータを確認するしかないのでしょうか。